# Команды администраторам, как сделать Python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Как в боте сделать, чтобы только администраторы бесед могли писать некоторые команды бота?
Vk_api.
Примерный код моей команды:

```
            if msg[0] in ['!призыв', '!пр']:
            sender(id, f'@all слушайте.\nВажная информация: {" ".join(msg[1:])}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция для получения администраторов чата будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
def get_chat_admins(api, peer_id):
    chat_users = api.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=peer_id)['items']
    return [
        i['member_id'] for i in chat_users if 'is_admin' in i
    ]
```

Передавать надо объект API и peer_id чата, который приходит вместе с событием. Подробнее можно прочитать здесь: https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversationMembers.